# How to manage exported block configuration that site users can override?

Tags: 8, configuration, deployment

Using core config management, we export configuration from developer's site instances and put than under version control. Eventually, this configuration is merged and ends up in production, where we import it thru either Drush or the UI.
Trouble is, site owners have permissions to update block configuration, and this overrides our exported configuration.

What is the intended workflow in this case?

Put more generically: how to manage exported configuration that can be overriden by users (with a core CM workflow)?

Comment: I think that if your site users consider block configuration "content", then it should not be managed by configuration management.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't (yet) a way to exclude a configuration item from being managed by configuration management.  The gray area of what is content and what is config will remain for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> Trouble is, site owners have permissions to update block configuration, and this overrides our exported configuration.

I thinks it's a bad idea to give site owner to change something in site-configuration. Site owner should take care only about site's content and should have permission to change site's configuration(block's configuration it's a site configuration).

Answer (score 0):

My team will be altering our deployment process to ensure any production changes are incorporated into the exported configuration before final deployment.

- Setup local environment to match code on production
- Export configuration from production & overwrite local configuration
- Stash or commit any changes
- Merge with latest development code
- Deploy code to production

Ideally, if we're aware of any in-production changes we will export and merge them during development as soon as possible, rather than waiting to do one big merge before deployment.